# How to hide options not selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a dropdown of options which is automatically selected.

What I'm trying to do is hide options not selected. That is, if I click book now for a specific hotel named A and I'm brought to the booking page where hotel A is automatically selected in the dropdown, how can I then hide hotel B, C and D

Comment: You you mind explaining more or adding a picture? I don't fully understand the question, sorry :/

Comment: Ideally, on the second page where the hotel A is automatically selected should not be a select box. but you can make a label that this is the selected value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do this on page_load/doc_ready:

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  $('#selectID').val("C");
  $('#selectID').find(':not(:selected)').hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id='selectID'>
  <option value="">select</option>
  <option value="A">one</option>
  <option value="B">two</option>
  <option value="C">three</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand what you really want, but what I understand you have some hotels and when a user selected one hotel, you want to hide other hotels.

```js
$(function() {

  $('#hotels').change(function() {
    var selected = $(this).val();
    console.log(selected);
    $("#select-div select").hide();
    $('#' + selected).show();


  });

});
```

```css
#select-div select {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="hotels">
  <option value="">--Select one hotel--</option>
  <option value="hotelA-rooms">Hotel A</option>
  <option value="hotelB-rooms">Hotel B</option>
  <option value="hotelC-rooms">Hotel C</option>
</select>

<div id="select-div">
  <select id="hotelA-rooms">
    <option>Room with 2 bed-$100</option>
    <option>Room with 2 bed-$200</option>
    <option>Room with 1 bed-$70</option>
  </select>

  <select id="hotelB-rooms">
    <option>Room with 1 bed-$170</option>
    <option>** Room with 1 bed-$370</option>
  </select>

  <select id="hotelC-rooms">
    <option>Room with 3 bed-$370</option>
    <option>Room with 5 bed-$500</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Try this, Hope this help you to understand selects better.